# Which regular expression should I use to validate weight in VB?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

In one of my program's procedures; I want to use a regular expression along with a match statement, to make sure that the user properly input's the weight of an individual into a  text box and also to make sure that it is entered in the right format. But I don't know which one to implement and am not very experienced with using the RegEx class in VB.Net.

However, I know that the regex which is used must make sure that the user has entered the information in the following format:

***123lb or 122223lb or 987LB or 23lB***

The number of digits used before the 'lb' does not matter but the 'lb' section must be case-insensitive. The RegEx must also look for no other letters apart from "lb".

For instance, some examples that shouldn't be matched:

- lb123 (The lb has to come after the digits)
- ab987 (The only letters that should be matched are lb)
- 4875638546cder (Here the number of digits are fine, but the letters aren't just lb)

Therefore in summary, the regex must:

- Look for no letters other than 'lb'
- Make sure that 'lb' comes after the digits entered by the user
- Be case-insensitive

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks for reading and have a good day!

Comment: [`^\d+[lL][bB]$`](https://regex101.com/r/J4cTct/2)

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up a label next to the text box with "lb" in it.
2. Constrain the user to only putting digits in the text box by using the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` event handlers.

Always better to prevent users from wrong input.

The above solution gets a little tricker if you are going to allow different weight units. In which case, I would swap the text box with "lb" for a list box of valid weight units. This way you can confidently get a number and a unit for your next calculations.

Comment: Or, instead of a `TextBox` one could use a [**`NumericUpDown`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx). :)

Comment: @VisualVincent - I thought of the NumericUpDown, but then considered the number of clicks the average user might have to use to get to the right result.

Comment: You do know that you can enter numbers with the keyboard in a `NumericUpDown`, right? You don't _have_ to use the up/down buttons.

Comment: @v: I did, just anticipating human behaviour. And your original comment still stands - `NumericUpDown` is another valid approach.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my cup of tea since I think the suggestions so far could've taken .NET's [**`RegexOptions`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) into consideration, which gives you the possibility to construct a simpler pattern.

Assuming `WeightTextBox` is the text box where the user enters his/her weight:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(WeightTextBox.Text, "^\d+LB$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
    'Correct input.
Else
    'Invalid input.
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxButtons.Error)
End If
```

**Pattern explanation:**

```
^\d+LB$

^          => Match beginning of string (or line, if RegexOptions.Multiline is set).
\d+        => Match one or more numerical characters.
LB         => Match "LB" (without quotes).
$          => Match end of string (or line, if RegexOptions.Multiline is set).
```

`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` makes the match case-insensitive, meaning it'll match `Lb`, `lB` or `lb` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]+[lL][bB]` wil do the trick.

Explanation:

`[0-9]+` matches 1 or more numbers

`[lL]` matches l or L

`[bB]` matches b or B

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Keep in mind that you must also verify that the match is the entire string. Right now your pattern allows for instance `This: 122LB is not my weight`, since `122LB` is present somewhere in the string (but it is not the entire string).